How to resolve CSRF/XSRF issue while working in .Net with ReactJS
I have tried with many solutions but still the issue has not resolved yet,
Here I am sharing one of my solution where if I send token back to server the controller with [ValidateAntiForgery] is always giving "Bad Request 400", If I remove middle-ware API works fine,
After trying with different approaches I am in same loop.
Note - I am using .Net 3.1 and Its created as MVC but we are using as Web API.
// Startup.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        //services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN");
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowReactApp", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
        // Extension method comes from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery` package
        services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
        });

        //services.AddScoped<AntiforgeryMiddleware>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("AllowReactApp");
        //app.UseMiddleware<AntiforgeryMiddleware>();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}

// AntiforgeryMiddleware.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

public class AntiforgeryMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;

    public AntiforgeryMiddleware(IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        _antiforgery = antiforgery;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        var isGetRequest = string.Equals("GET", context.Request.Method, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (!isGetRequest)
        {
            await _antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context);
        }
        await next(context);
    }
}

// DataController .cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/data")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult GetData()
    {
        // Your data retrieval logic here
        var data = new { message = "Data from API" };
        return Ok(data);
    }

}

Here If I call API /api/data passing token from ReactJS by passing header "X-XSRF-TOKEN", It always give me 400 Error, but If I remove [ValidateAntiForgeryToken], everything works fine.
Please share your suggestions and experience to resolve CSRF/XSRF issue with React and .Net.
